# Rendering data to the templates Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display the data from table using dynamic url.
However, when I try to do so, it just rendered out the attribute of the table instead. But when I use the same syntax to print on the shell, it works

**here is my view**

```py
def taches(request):
    taches = JobServices.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'taches.html', {'taches': taches})
    else:
        print('User is authenticated')
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'taches.html', {'taches': taches})

def service_fait(request, my_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        elements = JobServices.objects.filter(id=my_id)
        for element in elements:
            print(element.service_name)
            print(element.hour)
            print(element.user)
            print(element.description)
        return render(request, 'services_faits.html', {'elements': elements})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Here is the dynamic url:

```
path('servicefait/<str:my_id>',  views.service_fait, name='servicefait')
```

The taches.html template:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>{{ user }}, voici les tâches disponibles pour vous</h2>
<div class="row">
    {% for tache in taches %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ tache.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ tache.service_name }}</h5>
                    <b class="card-text">{{ tache.amount }} VT pour {{ tache.hour }} heures </b></p>
                    <a href="{% url 'servicefait' tache.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Postuler</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

services_faits.html template:

```
<div class="container">
{% for element in elements %}
    <p>element.service_name</p>
    <p>element.hour</p>
    <p>element.amount</p>
    <p>element.description</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the output of the web page:

```
element.service_name

element.hour

element.amount

element.description
```

And the shell is working properly as it shows the content of the above attribute.
Normally when I click the href link in taches.html it should redirect to the dynamic url by executing the method service_fait in the view

And finally, here is the model:

```py
class JobServices(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="nom du service")
    hour = models.IntegerField(default="Heures")
    amount = models.FloatField(default="Cout")
    service_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, default="annonce")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Is that for loop over `taches` part of `services_faits.html`? Your context variable is `elements` so are you also looping over that in your template to display the element data?

Comment: No, this forloop is not for services_faits.html, but for taches.html. I updated my code as you an see

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double brackets in your for loop to print element attributes.

```
{% for element in elements %}
    <p>{{ element.service_name }}</p>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```